# How to make mat-icon disabled in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Here i have multiple mat-icons, delete named mat-icon i want to make disabled i use disabled properties on this but it gives error like(Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-icon') so how to show particular mat-icon disabled in angular 6?

```
<mat-icon color="warn" style="cursor: pointer;" [disabled]="payloadArray.enabled != 'true' ">delete</mat-icon>
<mat-icon color="warn" style="cursor: pointer;">person_add</mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `mat-icon` inside button tag and then you can use disabled

Try this,

```
<button mat-icon-button [disabled]="payloadArray.enabled != 'true' " color="primary" >
   <mat-icon color="warn" style="cursor: pointer;" >delete</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: i dont want to use button that is my limitation

Comment: This will not display as button "mat-icon-button" this attribute remove style of button and display only icon

Comment: Just try it and see how it will looks

Comment: If you want the button shape/outlines use something different instead of mat-icon-button, like mat-stroked-button. That should work fine.

Answer (score 13):

Use ngClass directive to add disable

```
<mat-icon color="warn" [ngClass]="{'disable':payloadArray.enabled !== true}"(click)="onClick()">delete</mat-icon>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4jdvc9

Comment: it give same error Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-icon'

Comment: sorry type mistake remove disabled

Comment: it makes only non clickable not make disabled

Comment: do you have any parent element for mat-icon?

Comment: I guess you miss one double quotes character to close the ngClass directive.

Answer (score 4):

Although late at the party I figured out the following CSS with `[ngClass]="{'disable':condition...}"`

```
.disable:hover{
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
.disable:active{
    pointer-events: none;
}
mat-icon.disable {
    filter:opacity(0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's all post but what about two mat-icon?

```
<mat-icon *ngIf="payloadArray.enabled == 'true'" 
  color="warn" style="cursor: pointer;">
    delete
</mat-icon>
<mat-icon *ngIf="payloadArray.enabled != 'true'" 
  "color="warn" style="opacity:.5">
    delete
</mat-icon>
```

Comment: took the opacity idea from Eliseo but implemented it trough ngClass, Chellappan வ idea: 
template: [ngClass]="{'description-icon-disabled': disabled}"
scss: .description-icon-disabled { opacity: 0.5; }

and click disabled trough ts
template: (click)="onIconClicked()"
ts: public onIconClicked(): void {
    if (this.disabled) {
      this.iconClicked.emit();
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

I've found the source of this issue:
Make sure that this line exists at your component code (mock.component.ts):

```
import { MatButtonModule } from "@angular/material/button";`
```

And these lines present at your app module loader (app.module.ts):

```
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  *etc...*
})
```

PS: I had the same issue with <mat-button/> - the similar fix should work with <math-icon/> as well, but you need to use the name of your component instead of the button there.

Answer (score -2):

Here, You need to change use **mat-icon** inside the **button**

<button mat-icon color="warn" style="cursor: pointer;"[disabled]="payloadArray.enabled != 'true' ">delete

Comment: Your answer might be correct, but the accepted answer already uses the same approach.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see it on before